# Program that finds smallest positive integer NOT present in an array. How could I make the code more readable?

Tags: java

```
    package practice;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class SmallestPositiveIntegerNotInArray {

        public static int solution(int[] a) {
        int solutionRet = 1;

        Arrays.sort(a);

        if (a.length == 0) {  //if empty return 1 
            return solutionRet;
        } else if(a.length == 1) { //if 1 element, return 1 or 2
            if(solutionRet == a[0]) {
                return solutionRet + 1;
            } else {
                return solutionRet;
            }
        } else if(a[a.length - 1] < 1) { //if all negatives, return 1
            return solutionRet;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i] > solutionRet) {
                    if (a[i] > solutionRet + 1) {
                        if (a[i - 1] == solutionRet) {
                            return solutionRet + 1;
                        } else {
                            return solutionRet;
                        }
                    }
                    solutionRet++;
                } else if (a[i] == solutionRet) {
                    if (a[i] + 1 < a[i + 1] && a[i + 1] < a.length) {
                       return solutionRet + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (solutionRet == a[a.length - 1]) { //if the last num is same as solution, add 1
            solutionRet++;
        }
        return solutionRet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testArray[] = {};

        System.out.println(solution(testArray));

    }
}
```

Any suggestions for improving readability welcome, explanation for suggestion not necessary but appreciated.

If you know/find a more efficient way of doing this I would also appreciate if you told me/guided me in the right direction

Comment: This question clearly belongs to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

```
class SmallestPositiveIntegerNotInArray {

    public int solution(int[] a) {

        HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        int smallInt = 1;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++) {
            hashSet.add(a[i]);                     
        }

         while (hashSet.contains(smallInt)) {
             smallInt++;
            }

        return smallInt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to sort the array, and iterate through, looking for the next element you'd expect if the positive ints are contiguous. The downside is that you have to destroy the ordering of the array (unless you copy the array and sort that).

```
Arrays.sort(a);
int expectedNext = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  if (a[i] > 0) {
    if (a[i] != expectedNext) return expectedNext;
    ++expectedNext;

    while ((i+1) < a.length && a[i] == a[i+1])) {
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
return aa.length + 1;
```

A non-destructive way is to use a `BitSet` to record the numbers that are present, and then look for the first non-set bit (not including zero):

```
BitSet bits = new BitSet(a.length);
for (int aa : a) {
  if (aa > 0 && aa < a.length) {
    bits.set(aa);
  }
}
return bits.nextClearBit(1);
```

Comment: the first solution you suggested didn't work with the array: {-1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 5}, it returned 2 instead of 3. But your second solution works fine! I didn't know what BitSet is but i'll research them now, thanks.

Comment: @OneandOnly fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    int num = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] > 0) {
                if (A[i] == num) {
                    num++;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think sorting array first will consuming time, that is not efficient for code performance.
you could try the following simple code:

```
public static int solution2(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
     Arrays.sort(A);
     int smallest =1 ;
     for (int i=0 ; i< A.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(A[i]);
         if (A[i]==smallest) // to increase smallest
             smallest++;  
     }

   return smallest; 
 }
```

Comment: Post says "sorting array first will consuming time, that is not efficient for code performance", then immediately on line 3 of proposed solution has Arrays.sort(A).